# Сортировка многомерного массива, как работает usort()

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

У меня есть такой массив.

```
Array(
array(
   'name' => 'title 1',
   'price' => 200
   'id' => '737362'
)
array(
   'name' => 'title 2',
   'price' => 100
   'id' => '737363'
))
```

Нужна была сортировка по цене. Тут в соседней теме подсмотрел код:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
return ($a['price'] - $b['price']);});
```

Код работает отлично, проблем нет. Но я не могу понять КАК он работает. Объясните, что происходит? Зачем мы вычитаем?

Comment: Для этого надо не подсмотреть в соседней теме, а посмотреть в мануал языка программирования и прочитать описание функции [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) ... вообще изучение основ языка и основных методов работы с массивами/строками/файлами - хорошее занятие ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Зачем мы вычитаем?

Очень хороший вопрос.

Вычитаем мы потому, что так работает функция [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php): функция, которую мы передаем в качестве аргумента, должна возвращать положительное число, если первый аргумент больше второго; отрицательное - если меньше; и ноль - если аргументы равны. Это, собственно, и позволяет функции понять, в каком порядке ранжировать элементы массива.

Ну а получить такой результат проще всего вычитая первый операнд из другого!

Вот со строками получается сложнее - для их сортировки приходится использовать функцию strcmp(), которая также возвращает 1, -1 и 0 в описанных случаях.